# Scrapy multiple callback issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hello I wrote this spider to get new products on starturl. However, I am having issues writing another callback to parse the new product and then go back to normal parse callback in which is again continues to crawl for new products. 
This is what i have now

```
    def parse(self, response):
    products = Selector(response).xpath(
        '//div[@class="browsing-product-list"]//figure[contains(@class,"browsing-product-item")]')

    for product in products:
        item = StartItem()
        item['name'] = product.xpath('.//a/figcaption/p[2]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['link'] = product.xpath('.//meta[3]/@content').extract()[0]
        #New callback method to parse new url found not sure how to implement
        yield Request(StartURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=70)
        ru = scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(item['link']), callback=self.parseProduct)
        ru.meta['item'] = item
        yield ru

def parseProduct(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    imageUrls = response.xpath('id("img")/option/text()').extract()
    item['image_urls'] = imageUrls
    yield item
```

So please any help would be great
new edit below

```
    Superurl = "https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers"
    class SuperSpider(Spider):
        name = "SuperSpider"
        allowded_domains = ["randomtester.com"]
        start_urls = [SuperURL]

    def __init__(self):
        logging.critical("starting superspider.")

    def parse(self, response):
        products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="browsing-product-list"]//figure[contains(@class,"browsing-product-item")]')

        for product in products:
            item = SuperItem()
            item['name'] =product.xpath('.//a/figcaption/p[2]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = product.xpath('.//meta[3]/@content').extract()[0]
            # Not sure how to implement this to request the new url to parse  
            ru = scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(item['link']), callback=self.parseProduct)
            ru.meta['item'] = item
            yield ru
        yield Request(SuperURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=70)


    def parseProduct(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        imageUrls = response.xpath('id("size")/option/text()').extract()
        item['image_urls'] = imageUrls
        yield item
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I am unsure if this is the proper way to implement multiple callbacks as when i ran the crawler, it didnt work. It would would as normal and no request the new url when found

Comment: Can you update the post with the complete class code with proper indentation?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Just edited it. So the issue is callingback parseProduct as it seem i cant yield 2 callback options.

Comment: `yield Request(SuperURL, ...` in the parse method is redundant; it will call the original URL again, with the same results. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: @jschnurr the callback is for monitoring where new/updated products will be posted. Pretty much a New Arrivals page. The second call back i wish to add  is to join the new url  send a request and parse the product page. Then back to self.parse to again continue to crawl for new products.

Comment: I would rather use `cron` in Linux to run spider periodically (with 1 minute delay)

Comment: Your code seems OK. You didn't add url in question so we can't test it and see problem. If you run again the same page then you get page with the same products which you don't have to scrape. If page uses JavaScript to add items then maybe better find url used by JavaScript to get data from server and use this url to get new items.

Comment: ok, I agree with @furas you should use an external scheduler, but in any case it should work. The parse method can yield multiple items.  Your code should return n+1 Request objects - n being number of products on the page, and 1 being the call to Superurl. How many are you getting?

Comment: @furas so in theory do I keep the first yield then("yield Request(SSenseURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=70)".

Comment: @jschnurr when i ran it in shell without(yield Request(SSenseURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=70) i get proper output. However, it ends once all products are scraped. I need it to constantly crawl though for new urls not end when it goes through the all xpaths.

Comment: in theory your code should work. I think yield sends request to engine but for some reason engine doesn't use this request to get page again, or server responses with error (ie. 404) and engine skips this response.

Comment: you didn't put real url so we can't test your code and see problem

Comment: Thank you I will let it run, if not i will edit the full site and perhaps you can try . thanks so much @furas

Comment: Okay it didnt work. I edited the script to see the proper url. If you can solve the flaw please let me know. Scrapy just gets killed when running it after a minute or so. @furas

Comment: I run code and it works correctly - I see it gets all items on page and later it gets main page again and again and it doesn't stop.

Comment: yes, but i need it to get the xpath in parseProduct aswell @furas . When i put another callback i get duplicate error.

Answer (score 0):

I get your code and create standalone script which can run without project
and it works without problem - so I don't know what problem you have.

Currently it even downloads images because your version gets wrong data.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import logging
import json

SuperURL = "https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/sneakers"

class SuperSpider(Spider):

    name = "SuperSpider"

    start_urls = [SuperURL]

    def __init__(self):
        logging.critical("starting superspider.")

    def parse(self, response):

        products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="browsing-product-list"]//figure[contains(@class,"browsing-product-item")]')
        #products = response.xpath('//figure[@class="browsing-product-item"]')

        for product in products:
            #item = SuperItem()
            item = {}
            item['name'] = product.xpath('.//a/figcaption/p[2]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = product.xpath('.//meta[3]/@content').extract()[0]
            # Not sure how to implement this to request the new url to parse  
            ru = Request(url=response.urljoin(item['link']), callback=self.parseProduct)
            ru.meta['item'] = item
            yield ru
            #yield Request(url=response.urljoin(item['link']), callback=self.parseProduct, meta={'item': item})

        yield Request(SuperURL, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, priority=70)

    def parseProduct(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']

        all_scripts = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()

        for script in all_scripts:
            if 'window.INITIAL_STATE=' in script:
                images = json.loads(script[21:])["products"]["current"]["images"]
                item['image_urls'] = [x.replace('__IMAGE_PARAMS__', 'b_white,c_lpad,g_center,h_960,w_960/c_scale,h_680/f_auto,dpr_1.0') for x in images]

        yield item

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 

    # download images and convert to JPG
    # it needs `yield {'image_urls': [url]}` in `parse()`
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
    'IMAGES_STORE': '.',
})
c.crawl(SuperSpider)
c.start()
```

---

I use `Python 3.6.2` and `Scrapy 1.4.0` on `Linux Mint 18.2`

```
import sys
print('Python:',  sys.version)

import scrapy
print('Scrapy:', scrapy.__version__)
```

Comment: parseProduct xpath leads to sizes in the product url. I must have named the variable images by accident . I already scrapped the product images .